# Most efficient way of multithreading processes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-multithreading

Assume I have this script:

```
def connect():
    print('[*] Checking for updates...')
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'apt-get', 'update'])
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'apt-get', 'upgrade'])

    print('[+] Starting Tor service...')
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'service', 'tor', 'start'])

    vpn_path = str(input('[*] Type the path where your .ovpn files are: '))
    os.chdir(vpn_path)
    path = os.listdir(vpn_path)
    for file in path:
        if file.lower().endswith('ovpn'):
            print(file)

    vpn = str(input("Enter a .ovpn file name to connect to: "))
    if vpn in path:
        subprocess.call(['sudo', 'openvpn', '--config', vpn])
```

The first two subprocess.calls run in succession - first the system is updated and then Tor is started. After this, the script needs to initiate a VPN connection. The only problem is that the script won't progress until the OpenVPN process is stopped. As soon as the openvpn subprocess is called, it should be opened and run in a new terminal while the script continues. I've seen a few questions similar to this, but they use popen and I'm not sure if they will be able to efficiently solve my problem. Is there a simple and efficient way of doing this in python3?

EDIT (new code):

```
vpn = str(input("Enter a .ovpn file name to connect to: "))
vpncommand = 'sudo openvpn --config ' + "'" + vpn + "'"
vpnprocess = subprocess.Popen(vpncommand, shell=True)
vpnprocess.wait()
```

Comment: Try using `subprocess.Popen("command")` instead of `subprocess.call()`. `Call` blocks but `Popen` doesn't.

Comment: It will give effectively the same result you want.

Comment: @Krishi I edited the post, the code at the very bottom is what I'm trying right now. Before I can type Auth Username for the server it automatically closes. Also it doesn't open in a new shell.

Comment: @Krishi I'd also like to mention that it freezes my terminal from inputting anything after running the script twice, which is not ideal.

Comment: Why do you need to run the command using the terminal? Don't use `shell = True`

Comment: @Krishi Fixed the terminal malfunctions using Popen's wait(). I need to execute the subprocess in a different terminal window because OpenVPN needs to be running in the background while the script is still being used.

Comment: Another attempt, I tried opening it in a new shell like this: vpnprocess = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'sudo', 'openvpn', '--config', vpn])  but it just occupies both terminals because the python script is running the new terminal process which is running the openvpn.